# If statement that checks a list of numbers

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I want to write an if statement that will return if a variable does not equal one number in the list.  Conceptually I want it to do this:

```
if (VARX [DOES NOT EQUAL ONE OF THESE NUMBERS] 194||301||177||249||22||131||56. . .){ return; }
```

The actual list of numbers I have is approx 250 different numbers.  Is there an easy way to accomplish this with one if statement?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```js
const a = 10;
if(![1, 2, 3, 4, 5].includes(a)) {
  console.log('Pass!');
}
```

Or you could use a [`set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set):

```js
const a = 10;
const numbers = new Set([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);

if(!numbers.has(a)) {
  console.log('Pass!');
}
```

Comment: One being efficient with respect to space, and the other with respect to time... respectively, for the use case of finding an element within the collection..

Answer (score 0):

> You can also do in this way by passing your array to IF condition

```html
<script>
const tocheck = 10;
var list=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
if( list.includes(tocheck)) {
  alert('Element Exist!');
}
else{
alert('Element Does Not Exist!');
}
</script>
```